# Algolia AngularInstantSearch Pagination and Map

Tags: angular, dictionary, state, algolia

I am looking to make a UI with results with pagination on one side and a map on the other side. The problem that I have is that I want that both searches share the same filters but one should return just a page of results and the other all the results available.

I am using doing this in Angular so I am using two ais-instantsearch tags. The first one contains all the filters. How do I get to bind both searches to the same filters?

Regards!

Comment: You can use that custom filter in both the field add some code for more support

Comment: But I don't want to have the filters duplicated. Just one filter that filters both searches. (@HitechHitesh) This should be so easy such a simple requirement, to be able to get a state and set a state on the InstantSearch, I don't get why they manage everything internally in such an obscure way.

Comment: Add some code for more support